# Use of sightseeing

Tags: vocabulary

I need to used the word '***sightseeing***' in a sentence. I found dictionaries binding this term as:

> the activity of visiting interesting buildings and places as a tourist

Is this necessary that you visit interesting buildings and places, only then your visit will be an activity of sightseeing? Can't we use this for things that are imaginary? Such as if we say:

```
He was sightseeing heavens.
```

Is there any problem in this? I feel English is a very flexible language. We don't have to stick to every part of a definition a dictionary tells. Take another example:

> He was sightseeing on the moon.

There will be no buildings on the moon; still, this sentence seems be ok to me.

Am I on right lines?

Comment: You can say. In fact, Timothy already had [sightseeing *in* heaven](https://www.amazon.com/Sightseeing-Heaven-Audio-Timothy-Flemming/dp/B00RQUYD9G)!

Answer (score 2):

You can’t say “He was sightseeing heavens”, because “sightseeing” needs a preposition, and “heaven” is (normally) singular. You could say “He was sightseeing in heaven”. “He was sightseeing on the moon” is fine — even with no buildings, there are still sights to see. You can go sightseeing in the Grand Canyon, for example. But it has to be casual tourist-type activity — you can’t say that a scientist doing a geological survey on the moon is sightseeing, unless you’re being ironic or metaphorical.